# Shorten part of the code with the condition

Tags: php

There is a block of conditions.Help to shorten and improve this part of the code

```
$stock = $row['KOLVO_T'];

if ($row['CENA'] < 1000 && $row['KOLVO_T'] == 1) {
   $stock = 0;
}

if ($row['CENA'] >= 1000 && $row['KOLVO_T'] == 1) {
   $stock = $row['KOLVO_T'];
}
if ($row['KOLVO_T'] >= 2) {
   $stock = $row['KOLVO_T'];
}

return $stock;
```

Comment: Are these `if` statements supposed to be exclusive?

Comment: Yes, It is necessary to return the result $stock

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the point, but here's the simplest I could do:

```php
$stock = $row['KOLVO_T'];

if ($row['CENA'] < 1000 && $stock == 1) {
   $stock = 0;
}

return $stock;
```

The last two conditional blocks are useless since they repeat an operation you already did before the first conditional block, and their condition can't be verified if the first is.